# PDFlib - is it possible to measure combined height/width of all elements on the page, excluding whitespace that surrounds all these elements?

Tags: pdflib

**Given**:

- arbitrary size PDF page (could be taller and/or wider than standard formats)
- a script that positions random shapes (triangles, cirles, images) of random sizes at random coordinates on that page

**Question**:

What PDFlib function should I use to measure the width and height of rectangular area that contains all rendered elements (think of "selection area" if you're in a vector editor)?

Comment: I think it's called "Art Box" - area occupied by rendered elements.

Comment: My task can be rephrased. I do not necessarily need to know the resulting height of page containing random elements. But I must know the bottom edge, so I could append more objects.